# SSIS Command text with function

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I'm developing a DTS to query the database with parameters and these parameters must be within a function that returns me a table.
The query is:

```
Select  left(EP.EspecificacionDeProductoCodigo,6) As Codigo,
        left(EP.EspecificacionDeProductoDescripcion,25) As Descripcion,
        SUM(SP.ProductoCantidad) As Cantidad,
        PE.PrecioDeEspecificacionPrecioConImpuestos As PrecioUnitario
From    Producto.StockDeProductoFn(?, ?, ?, NULL, getdate()) SP
Join    Producto.EspecificacionDeProductoVw EP On
        (   EP.EspecificacionDeProductoID   = SP.EspecificacionDeProductoID)
Left Join Producto.PrecioDeEspecificacionFn(?, ?, Null, Null, getdate()) PE On
        (   PE.EspecificacionID = EP.EspecificacionDeProductoID)
Group By
    left(EP.EspecificacionDeProductoCodigo,6),
    left(EP.EspecificacionDeProductoDescripcion,25),
    PE.PrecioDeEspecificacionPrecioConImpuestos 
Order By
    left(EP.EspecificacionDeProductoCodigo,6)
```

As you can see takes 5 parameters to be environment variables according lei. The problem is that when I put this query in the OLE DB Source Editor, and pressed the Parameters button gives me the following error: "Parameters cannot be extracted from the SQL command. The provieder might not help to parse parameter information from the command. In that case, use the "SQL command from variable" access mode, in which the entire SQL command is stored in a variable"

I can put this query As well as this and make it work?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

trying turning off validation and then running the package

Answer (score 0):

The Parameter mapping window in SSIS is totally brian dead. The work around is the dynamically build your SQL in a variable using expressions, then use that variable as the source.